# ZK Client attributes not working with Datebox

Tags: spell-checking, zk

We are using [Keyoti Spell Cheker](http://keyoti.com/products/java/spell-checkers.html) in our web application and its working fine with Zk but I have to add NoSpell checking for `Datebox` so I have to add the following line in my code:

```
<zk xmlns:x="xhtml" xmlns:zk="zk" xmlns:d="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zk/client/attribute">
```

And in component I have to add an attribute like this: `d:nospell='true'`

It's working fine for `textbox` and `intbox` but not for `datebox`.  I have added it like this:

```xml
<datebox d:nospell='true'></datebox>
```

But the spell checker is still doing spell checking in the `datebox` component so I just inspected the element and the HTML code looks like this:

```html
<i id="t_3475" class="z-datebox" nospell="true"><iframe id="t_3475-real_IF" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" src="http://localhost:7080/module-web/core/a.rapidspellweb?t=r&n=blank.html" style="display: none; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; border-width: 1px; border-color: rgb(171, 173, 179) rgb(227, 233, 239) rgb(227, 233, 239); border-style: solid; height: 19px; width: 86px; background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(255, 255, 255); animation-delay: 0s; animation-direction: normal; animation-duration: 0s; animation-fill-mode: none; animation-iteration-count: 1; animation-name: none; animation-play-state: running; box-shadow: none; caption-side: top; clear: none; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); content: none; counter-increment: none; cursor: text; direction: ltr; empty-cells: show; align-self: stretch; flex: 0 1 auto; flex-direction: row; order: 0; justify-content: flex-start; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-size-adjust: none; font-stretch: normal; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: 400; ime-mode: auto; letter-spacing: normal; list-style: disc outside none; opacity: 1; padding: 2px; page-break-after: auto; page-break-before: auto; page-break-inside: auto; pointer-events: auto; quotes: "“" "”" "‘" "’"; transform: none; transform-origin: 50% 50% 0px; perspective-origin: 50% 50%; perspective: none; backface-visibility: visible; transition-delay: 0s; transition-duration: 0s; transition-property: all; unicode-bidi: normal; vertical-align: baseline; color-interpolation: srgb; color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb; fill: rgb(0, 0, 0); fill-opacity: 1; fill-rule: nonzero; filter: none; flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); flood-opacity: 1; image-rendering: auto; lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); marker: none; mask: none; shape-rendering: auto; stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); stop-opacity: 1; stroke: none; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 4; stroke-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1px; vector-effect: none;" tabindex="null"></iframe><input id="t_3475-real" class="z-datebox-inp" type="text" size="11" value="" autocomplete="off" style="display: none;" oldvalue="2013-08-13"></input>
```

How can we fix this issue so that we can disable spell checking on `datebox` components?

Comment: it works for me, you may upgrade your ZK version.